# Playframework is not comfortable with svn ,how to resolve?

Tags: eclipse, svn, playframework

When use svn for playframework project, the .svn hidden folders brings erros in some play commands:
for example:

```
D:\wwwroot\mss>play eclipsify
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.1, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is server01
~
JPDA port 8000 is already used. Will try to use any free port for debugging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\play", line 111, in <module>
    cmdloader.commands[play_command].execute(command=play_command, app=play_app,
 args=remaining_args, env=play_env, cmdloader=cmdloader)
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\framework\pym\play\commands\eclipse.py", line 33,
 in execute
    shutil.rmtree(eclipse)
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\python\lib\shutil.py", line 169, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\python\lib\shutil.py", line 169, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\python\lib\shutil.py", line 174, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\Tools\Java\play-1.1\python\lib\shutil.py", line 172, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
WindowsError: [Error 5] : 'D:\\wwwroot\\mss\\eclipse\\.settings\\.svn\\all-wcpro
ps'
```

delete the hidden .svn folders can resolve this ,but our team server is svn . Who can resolve this question but not delete the .svn folders?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have committed into the SVN repository the Eclipse configuration files (.settings folder and all others). This confuses the command, and anyway it should not be done.

Try to remove them and run the command again. It should work. Then make sure to remove those from the svn repo.

(Or switch to Mercurial/git ;)

Comment: I have to try the Mercurial. but It's not popular.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems .settings directory can't be deleted by Play! framework.
Remove all Eclipse config files from your SVN repository.

Play! has no problem with Subversion.

Comment: this is a problem ,play should update to ignore the .svn folders

Comment: No, problem comes from eclipse files being in SVN and being locked. No one can deleted a locked file. Play! is clean by deleting the Eclipse conf files before recreating them.